# Calculus vs calculation

Tags: etymology, word-usage, slang, ambiguity, north-american-english

It is becoming more popular on American talk shows to say "calculus" instead of "calculation." To my mind, calculus is either a branch of Mathematics or a stone like in the gall bladder. Any comments?

Comment: Definition #2 at http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calculus is _calculation_.

Comment: It can also be tartar deposits on teeth.

Comment: The branch of mathematics is sometimes called **the** calculus, to distinguish it from calculations in general.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment. But if more people are using 'calculus' for a calculation, then soon it may become a reasonable alternative rather than a mistake.

Comment: @Mitch As Barmar's comment and Sven Yargs' answer point out, one definition of "calculus" is "calculation," so using it that way is not a mistake.

Comment: @Nicole: Whatever the dictionaries say, it would be very misleading to tell a non-native speaker that you could use calculus as an alternative in the following "Multiplying 17 and 37 is a simple calculation".

Comment: @Mitch If dictionaries say it can be used that way, and people actually do use it that way, what exactly are you objecting to?

Comment: @Nicole: I'm saying that people don't actually use it that way. You're treating English as though it's defined by the dictionary, when really a dictionary is a messy approximation. See [China flushes India](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=17069) for similar mistakes in how Chinese is translated to English.

Comment: I'm a native speaker of American English, and I'm fairly sure never heard the word calculus used synonymously with calculation. To me, calculus always refers to the branch of mathematics. Can you give evidence of the word being used in the way you describe?

Answer (score 8):

*Calculus* in the sense of "calculation" has appeared in editions of Merriam-Webster's *Collegiate Dictionary* from the first one (published in 1898). In fact, this is the only mathematical definition of *calculus* in that dictionary:

> Any process of reasoning by the use of symbols ; any branch of mathematics that may involve calculation.

However, the subsequent rise of differential and integral calculus altered the dictionary's definitions considerably. The *Third Collegiate* (1916) has these relevant definitions for *calculus*:

> **2** A method of computation ; esp., a branch of higher mathematics (*differential and integral calculus*) by which problems involving motion or constant variation are solved. **3** A book containing the principles of this science.

By the time the *Seventh Collegiate* (1963) appeared, the "higher mathematics" sense of calculus appeared to be complete. Here are that dictionary's relevant definitions of *calculus*:

> **2** *archaic* **:** CALCULATION **3 a :** a method of computation or calculation in a special symbolic notation **b :** the mathematical methods comprising differential and integral calculus

So when did Merriam-Webster remove the "archaic" label from *calculus* in the sense of "CALCULATION"? It happened in 1983, with the release of the *Ninth Collegiate*:

> **calculus** (1666) **1 a :** a method of computation or calculation in a special notation (as of logic or symbolic logic) **b :** the mathematical methods comprising differential and integral calculus **2 :** CALCULATION

The only significant alteration to the entry for calculus to occur since the Ninth Collegiate was the addition in the Tenth Edition (1993) of this new and more general sense of the word:

> **4 :** a system or arrangement of intricate or interrelated parts

So from 1993 forward, Merriam-Webster has acknowledged the use of *calculus* in such phrases as "[a calculus of communicating systems](https://books.google.com/books?id=7L1PAQAAIAAJ&q=%22a+calculus+of%22&dq=%22a+calculus+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aeC2VNnOEsS7mQXJy4HIAQ&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA)."

It is hardly surprising that people who spent significant time speaking English between 1963 and 1983 should have a sense that using *calculus* to mean "calculation" is either old-fashioned (if they remember "archaic" instances of that usage from those years) or newfangled (if they don't). But calculus-as-calculation has a long history of usage in English, as well as lots of current usage; and in business meetings across the land, the fact that "calculus" sounds more impressive than "calculation" almost guarantees that its popularity in coming years will grow rather than diminish.

Comment: So in short, no harm to treat `calculus` as a synonym of `calculation`. Only the former gives a bit more *atmosphere*...

Comment: Calculus more commonly means a method of calculation or a system/framework for doing some kind of calculation, rather than a specific instance of a numerical calculation (e.g. a sum). The two are not entirely synonymous.